# $x^2y^3+x(1+y^2)y' = 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$x^2y^3+x(1+y^2)y' = 0$$

I´m trying to find if this equation is exact, but $M = x^2y^3\implies M_y = 3y^2x^2$ and $N=(x+xy^2)\implies N_x = 1+y^2$. Since those are different, I can't find this to be an exact equation. But I'm gonna try to find an integrating factor $\phi(x)$ (which depends only on $x$):

$$\phi x^2y^3+\phi(x+xy^2) = 0$$

Then I must have $O = \phi x^2y^3\implies O_y = \phi\cdot 3y^2x^2$ and $P = \phi(x+xy^2) \implies P_x = \phi(1+y^2)+\phi_x\cdot (x+xy^2)$

I must have:

$$O_y = P_x \implies \phi(1+y^2)+\phi_x\cdot (x+xy^2) = \phi\cdot 3y^2x^2\implies$$

$$\phi(1+y^2-3y^2x^2)+\phi_x\cdot (x+xy^2) = 0$$

This EDO is only easy to solve if I can put it in the form $\phi\cdot H(x) + \phi_x = 0$ or with $H(y)$. I didn't learn any method to solve it without this. I can't, however, see how can I put this equation to depend only on one variable. Is it possible?

Comment: Separation of Variables?

Comment: @Moo will it work and be easy? because my book taught me that I should find the integrating factor by analysing $(M_y -N_x)/N$ and see if it depends only on one variable, then throws me this exercise...

Comment: Well, after Separation of Variables, we have $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{y^2+1}{y^3}~ dy = - \int x~ dx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method of [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables): if $x\not =0$ and $y\not=0$ (note that $y=0$ is a stationary solution) then 
$$x=-\frac{(1+y^2)}{y^3}\cdot y'=\left(-\frac{1}{y^3}-\frac{1}{y}\right)\cdot y'$$
which implies that
$$\frac{x^2}{2}=\int x dx=\int\left(-\frac{1}{y^3}-\frac{1}{y}\right)dy=\frac{1}{2y^2}-\ln|y|+C.$$
Therefore a solution $y(x)$ satisfies the equation 
$$x^2=\frac{1}{y(x)^2}-\ln(y^2(x))+2C$$
for some constant $C$.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, my book, in the answers, suggests $y = \frac{1}{xy^3}$, why is your answer more complicated? How could I arrive at this one given by my book?

Comment: @Guerlando OCs The answer of your book is quite strange. Do you mind to check again the statement of the exercise?